# Trigger an event on clicking "OK" on the messagebox in an access form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access form in which after the user performs few operations a message box will appear. When the user clicks "OK" on the message box I want to close the current form and open a new form. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

the VBA code execution is suspended until the user clicks ok.  Therefore the next line of code after the msgbox call will be your spot to do the 'magic'

You want to open the new form first, then close the current form.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do it by just putting the code directly after the MsgBox command, or by checking the response of the user in a multi-response messagebox.  For example:

```
    If MsgBox("Do you really want to continue?" & vbCrLf, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then 
        DoCmd.Close MyFormName
    Else
        ...Perform some other function 
    End If
```

This will pop up a messagebox with both Yes and No buttons, and allows you to run some alternate code if the response is No.